# Trying to run a C# Discord Bot on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ with Windows 10 IoT

Tags: windows-iot, pi-3b+, c#

I have developed, in Visual Studio 2015, a C# Console Application which uses the Discord.Net API. It works great running on my PC, which has Windows 10, however I am looking to run the program 24/7 on a Raspberry Pi.

The device I have is a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+. It currently runs on the Raspberry Pi 3 B+ Technical Preview Build 17661 offered by Microsoft. I added all the files from my project's `\bin\Debug` directory to my Pi's SD Card. I open the Windows Device Portal, and enter the command prompt to run the `.exe` file from its path. However, doing so returns this error log:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationBinder' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer..ctor()
   at Discord.API.DiscordRestApiClient..ctor(RestClientProvider restClientProvider, String userAgent, RetryMode defaultRetryMode, JsonSerializer serializer)
   at Discord.API.DiscordSocketApiClient..ctor(RestClientProvider restClientProvider, WebSocketProvider webSocketProvider, String userAgent, String url, RetryMode defaultRetryMode, JsonSerializer serializer)
   at Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketClient.CreateApiClient(DiscordSocketConfig config)
   at Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketClient..ctor()
   at TutorialBot.Program.<RunBotAsyc>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at TutorialBot.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I am not exactly sure how to handle, or fix, this issue. I have looked around for solutions, but I haven't gotten very far. Some other methods I have tried in order to run my program haven't been very successful so, if possible, I would really like to try to make this work on this OS.

Comment: You should be more specific about the non-working solutions you found or the "Some other methods" you have tried. This would make it easier for us to understand what you already know or tried or to find a mistake you might have made.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it was a dotnetcore console application then with CMD `cd` into the projects directory and run `dotnet publish -r win8-arm`